# Brute Force Login Prevention With Iptables

Tags: security, authentication, iptables, brute-force

Let's say I have an website with a login page that runs at `localhost:4321`. 
I have a brute force script in python and when I run it I try to brute force the username and password. 
The question is how can I prevent this brute force attack  with iptables rules? I want to block this script for my `localhost:4321` website. It's also good, if i can block this for a number of seconds after a failed login.

I tried to prevent this in my code, but I want to prevent with iptables rules to learn that, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of systems:

- IDS - intrusion detection systems
- IPS - intrusion prevention systems

An IDS will only detect that you are attacked and log/report/alert. An IPS will try to stop the attack. Many are doing IDS. Very few are doing IPS. Why? Well, you could certainly dynamically implement iptables rules to drop traffic coming from certain IPs, but this will be:

1. Inaccurate - as many users may be sharing the same IP and not all of them are performing the attack.
2. Will lower the systems accessibility.
3. May be used to perform Denial of Service attacks.

If you need to protect rather try implementing a captcha mechanism.